# GetSystemTimeZone in English when OS in non-English

Tags: c#

In our C# application we are supporting multiple Languages.Now if application Language is English and the OS in which our application is installed in non-English(say Spanish).
When I try to retrieve SystemTime Zones using TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() it gives me in Spanish Language.Is there any way I can get it in English or is there any generic solution to it.

Answer (score 2):

[TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones.aspx)

"If your application requires time zones not found on the local computer, you can create custom time zones using the overloads of the CreateCustomTimeZone method. For more information, see How to: Create Time Zones Without Adjustment Rules and How to: Create Time Zones with Adjustment Rules."

Also,

"The GetSystemTimeZones method returns a collection of TimeZoneInfo objects only for time zones defined in the registry. It does not include time zones created using the overloads of the CreateCustomTimeZone method."

Comment: Actually I want the same time zone list but the list should be displayed in Englisgh culture i.e I want the Display Name in english rather than any other language.I am not adding any Custom Time Zone on my own.

Comment: DisplayName too is dealt with on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the current culture temporarily:

```
var orgCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture 
    = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture 
        = new CultureInfo("en-us");

var zones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
// get names here

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture 
    = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture 
        = orgCulture;
```

Comment: Improve your attitude if you want help.

Comment: Where in my comment you found my attitude wrong.Still sorry if I did hurt you.

Comment: I consider five exclamation marks being impolite and immature. We all answer questions in our spare time for free. Hence we choose questions being interesting. That said, the time zone names are probably being stored in the registry using the OS language only.

Comment: Oh I didn't knew that five exclamation mark give na immature and impolite gesture.If time zone names are probably being stored in the registry using the OS language only then is there no way I can make even display name of  visible in English for OS in non-English?

Comment: See Kris' answer. The values returned come from the registry and are therefore not localized.

Answer (score 0):

why not use DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()?